# Use callback function to create variables and use in a html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

Firstly excuse my ignorance with any inaccurate information I provide I a very new to javascript, jquery and json.

Anyway I have a script which pulls data from a json file and displays in a webpage with the help of javascript, jquery, ajax(i think) and json.

There is a callback for when I get back the results:

```
function searchCallback(data) {
                $(document.body).append('<h1>' + data.title + '</h1>');  
            }
```

And it works fine the like this. However I want `data.title` (json object) to be displayed in a html element of my choice without having to use $(document.body) because my page won't display correctly at I have other html elements outside the script.

As far as I know (excuse ignorance) with javascript I can possible add a variable and use it as follows:

```
var title = data.title;
```

And in my html:

```
<span id="title"></span>
```

or maybe there is cleaner way?

Anyway how do I achieve this. Thank you for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find an element and modify, jQuery makes this easy. Instead of `$(document.body).append` find an existing element by it's id, and then call the `text` method on it to replace the text inside that element with something new.

```
$('#title').text(data.title);
```

Comment: thank you so much exactly what i wanted. and what if the object is a string for an image file location. how would i put in an img tag?

Comment: Read up on http://api.jquery.com/. jQuery is very well documented library that you can explore yourself. But I'll give you a hint.  You will want to use the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to set the `src` property of an image. Good luck :)

Comment: fair enough I was chancing my arm! thanks so much!! :)